# How to initialize a lazy ServletRegistration in Java EE

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee, java-ee-8

I have a `ServletContextListener` and I'm running a `JSF 2.3` application on a `Tomcat 9` container. All is good however I need to have access to the `FacesContext` when the context is created.

As I am not using a deployment descriptor, so I am not registering the `FacesServlet` configuration, it seems that it is automatically registered by the container for the following reasons:

The following call will return `NULL` and as stated in the Java Doc, it returns `NULL` when there is already a created Servlet under the same name.

`sce.getServletContext().addServlet("FacesServlet", FacesServlet.class)`

The following call does return a value:

`ServletRegistration facesServlet = sce.getServletContext().getServletRegistration("FacesServlet");`

However since I haven't done any configurations, I did not set the `loadOnStatup` parameter, and so it is autoamtically set as `-1`.

Now being a negative number, this means that this Servlet is lazy, and so by calling `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` I am receiving `NULL` because it seems that Servlet hasn't initialized yet.

Now, of course, I can manually register the Servlet via a deployment descriptor but I would like to avoid that (just because I want to benefit from auto-configurations as much as I can).

I did not find a way to change the `loadOnStatup` value programmatically, is there a way to initialize this Servlet?

Comment: Unfortunately, i do not think if there is away you can do this. If you cannot trick the servlet registration to override the already configured `FacesServlet`, then you are only left with the `servlet` web.xml configuration.
Also check if you can set the value of `ServletContext.setInitParameter` for the ServletContext related to the FacesServlet.